# fadeToggle div container by id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have this function:

```
function showHideLayer(id)
{
    $("#" + id).fadeToggle();
}
```

and this php code:

```
echo "
<a id=\"answer-".$i."\" href=\"#\" onlick=\"showHideLayer('subMessages-".$i."'')\">
<b>".count($ansPostId)."</b> Antworten</a>
<br>
<div id=\"subMessages-".$i."\" style=\"display: none;\">
message
</div>
```

but it doesn't work

can anyone help me?

It should toggle the div in and out by clicking on the Link.

Thank you =)

Comment: How do you you call it ? use  `onclick` not onlick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misspelled `onclick`. Also you have a bad quote ordering.

Here is another suggestion how you can do this, since you use jQuery:

```
echo '<a id="answer-'.$i.'" href="#" class="answer" data-submessages="'.$i.'">
    <b>'.count($ansPostId).'</b> Antworten
</a>
<br>
<div id="subMessages-'.$i.'" style="display: none;">
    message
</div>';
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.answer').click(function() {
        var sm_id = $(this).attr('data-submessages');
        $('#subMessages-' + sm_id).fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/USWVJ/

For dynamically added DOM elements:

`$(document).on('click', 'element', function)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.answer', function () {
        var sm_id = $(this).attr('data-submessages');
        $('#subMessages-' + sm_id).fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: this is working fine, but i load the php code with ajax and after loading the content new, it stops working, any idea?

Comment: it's the snippet from my question. =)

Comment: Instead of using `$('.answer').click`, try `$('.answer').on('click',...`

Comment: sry, i don't really understand. What comes after the ',' ? $('.answer').on('click',function() ... ?

Comment: hm that doesn't work, it destroys all code coming after this. Seems like there is a missing token, or something like that.

Comment: ok i am not allowed to edit,it because its just one character... the " '" after click

Answer (score 1):

misspell "onlick" => "onclick"

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using jQuery. Use [`Attribute starts with selector.`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) Try this:

```
$("a[id^=answer]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div#subMessages-"+$(this).attr("id").split("answer-")[1]).fadeToggle();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ws47a/)**

Comment: @progNewFag: Have a checked demo fiddle? What is the error in your case?

Comment: i don't know, but i load that code with ajax, so maybe that doesn't work combined?

Comment: omg bad mistake...i didn't write it in the $(document).ready( function () { function :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is one single quote too many at the end of the id of the `showHideLayer` function.

Replace this...

```
onclick=\"showHideLayer('subMessages-".$i."'')\"
```

...with this...

```
onclick=\"showHideLayer('subMessages-".$i."')\"
```

**EDITED** Truth to be told, I didn't see this before and merely copied your code, but indeed, `onclick` missed a `c` in your code too. Credit goes to @Henriksjodahl for that who first detected this.

Comment: If it solved your issue, you might as well accept it as the best answer (big check mark below the voting buttons) ;)

Comment: that was just an upvote (assuming you did it), thanks for that! though it's still not accepted as the best answer... provided you do think this resolved it, of course, you may use the checkmark to do it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using JQuery try the following:

```
$(docuemnt).ready(function(){
   // if a link of class myclass is clicked this action is triggerd
   $("a.myclass").click(function(){
        e.preventDefault();// prevent default action
        var submsgid = "subMessages"+$(this).attr("id").split("answer-")[1];
        $("div#"+submsgid).fadeToggle();
   });
});
```

Try to avoid mixing ( " ) and ( ' ) together. This might look cleaner:

```
// your php code
?>
<a id="answer-<?php echo $i;?>" class="myclass" href="#">
    <b><?php echo count($ansPostId); ?></b> Antworten
</a>
<br>
<div id="subMessages<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display: none;">
   message
</div>
<?php
// your php code
```